# Can't get a div with specific class

Tags: jquery

I have a set of elements, each of which looks like this:

```
<div class="maindiv">
  <div id="55">
    <a class="aimg" onclick="showit(this);return false;">
      <img src="myjpg.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <div class="someclass"></div>
    <div class="getit"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

class "getit" has display set to "none". I need the "onclick=show" function to put the display of that "getit" classed div to "block".

I've tried the following inside the "showit()" function:

```
$(this).parent().find('.getit:first').css('display', 'block');
```

but it doesnt work...

I hope someone here can help me!

Comment: Is the missing `>` on the `a` tag just a typo in SO or copy/paste from your code?

Comment: yes, it was a typo, now fixed :-).

Comment: I've edited the "show()" to "showit()" to avoid any confusion with jquery's "show".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the onclick handler, as inline javascript usually is'nt the best solution, and prevent the default action in the click handler instead.

```
<div class="maindiv">
  <div id="55">
    <a class="aimg">
      <img src="myjpg.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <div class="someclass"></div>
    <div class="getit">dsdadsa</div>
  </div>
</div>​​​
```

Then just find the sibling with the right class and show it.

```
$(".aimg")​.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings(".getit").show();
})​;​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p2JxS/)

Or if you just have to have the onclick function (which is uneccessary) :

```
<div class="maindiv">
  <div id="55">
    <a class="aimg" onclick="showit(this);return false;">
      <img src="myjpg.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <div class="someclass"></div>
    <div class="getit">dsdadsa</div>
  </div>
 </div>

​<script type="text/javascript"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​>
    function showit(elem) {
        $(elem).siblings(".getit").show();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: a little explanation would make this a nice answer

Comment: @RuneFS - Not big on explaining stuff, but maybe that's a little better ?

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the `showit` function will represent the window object and not the `<a>` tag.

Use the parameter name used in the show function declaration, eg

```
function showit(element){
    //other stuff
    $(element).parent().find('.getit:first').css('display', 'block');
    //other stuff
}
```

or

```
function showit(){
    //other stuff
    $(arguments[0]).parent().find('.getit:first').css('display', 'block');
    //other stuff
}
```

To get to use `this` as the `<a>` tag without changing the `showit` function, you can [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
<a class="aimg" onclick="showit.call(this);return false;">
```

Also you can just bind event handlers to elements without having to mess around with attributes

```
$(".aimg")​.on('click', function() {
    //other stuff
    $(this).siblings(".getit").css('display', 'block');
    //other stuff
})​;​
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate the `div.getit` using the `.find()` function on the links parent element.  The `<div id="55">` element.

The key here is to convert the incoming event object (`e`) to a jQuery object by wrapping it in `$()` - so that you can use jQuerys handy `.parent()` and `.find()` functions.

```
function showit(e){
  $(e).parent().find('div.getit').show();
};
```

---

The jQuery documentation has [this](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to say about the `.show()` function -

> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'block')`, except
>   that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If
>   an element has a display value of `inline`, then is hidden and shown, it
>   will once again be displayed inline.
>
> Note: If using `!important` in your styles, such as `display: none
>   !important`, it is necessary to override the style using
>   `.css('display', 'block !important')` should you wish for `.show()` to
>   function correctly

Comment: Lix, I may not have been clear enough. I have the code above inside the "show()" function, together with some other code.

Comment: did you try the `div.getit` selector?

Comment: Lix, I think there may have been some confusion with my function being named "show", so I changed it to "showit"

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:-

### HTML:

```
<div class="maindiv">
  <div id="55">
    <a class="aimg">
      <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cfda66988653015c6791d5da11ebbc2c?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"/>
    </a>
    <div class="someclass"></div>
    <div class="getit"></div>
  </div>
 </div>​
```

### JS:

```
$('.aimg').one('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.getit:first').css('display', 'block');
});
```

### CSS:

```
.getit {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}​
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/rAKSz/)**